# how to pass data from response in yield call?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have code like this

```
export function* generateMotif({ payload }) {
    try {
        let { detail } = yield select(state => state.user);
        const result = yield call(API.generateMotif, payload, detail.api_token);
        
        yield put({
            type: types.GENERATE_MOTIF_SUCCESS,
            payload: result,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        yield put(handleError(err));

        yield put({
            type: types.GENERATE_MOTIF_FAILURE,
            payload: err,
        });
    }
}
```

result have data like username, URL, fileName, etc. Is it possible to pass specific data from result in sagas?

like I only want data URL or fileName, so I put my code like this

```
yield put({
     payload: result.data.url;
});
```

I already tried to debug `result` using `console.log(result.data.url)` to show `data` inside the result. But I got response `undefined`.

Did something miss in my code?

I hope you can give me some advice about how to solve this. Thankyou very much

Comment: Yes, you can use it like `yield put({ type: types.GENERATE_MOTIF_SUCCESS, payload: result.data.url });`. In your reducer, you can directly access the url using `payload`

Comment: @Nithish I already tying the opposite like in sagas, I write `yield put({ type: types.GENERATE_MOTIF_SUCCESS, payload: result });`, so in my reduces, I access the URL using `payload.data.url` 

I trying to debug `result` using `console.log(result.data.url` and its returns `undefined`, and still not working